# c++: Call derrived function from base constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

```
class Base
    {
    virtual void method()
        { cout << "Run by the base."; };
    public:
    Base() { method(); };
    };

class Derived: public Base
    {
    void method()
        { cout << "Run by the derived."; };
    };

void main()
    {
    Derived();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Run by the base.
```

How can one have the derived method run instead, without making a derived constructor?

Comment: -1 This question has been asked many times on SO, and you could have found it easily.

Comment: I tried but I didn't think to search the word "virtual". Anyway sorry to waste your time if you want me to close it tell me how, but I think the example sums it up well.

Comment: just google "calling virtual functions from constructor" you will find **tons** of useful information. I wish i could close the question due to "Use Google first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without adding extra code.

A common way to achieve this is to use a private constructor and a `create` function that first calls the constructor (via `new`) and then a second `finish_init` method on the newly created object. This does prevent you from creating instances of the object on the stack though.

Comment: Two phase creation of objects is a bad idea. The whole point of constructors is to avoid this. Learn about the PIMPL pattern (available in all good design pattern books).

Answer (score 3):

[Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Comment: Thank you! x) Lots of useful info.

Comment: you should vote to close as exact duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You can't since the "derived" part of the object has not been constructed yet so calling a member function from it would be undefined behavior.