# Subtleties of Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, super

Let's say `SList` is a `super class` of `TailList`.

If I execute the following codes,

```
SList s;
TailList t = new TailList();
s = t;
```

is this same as doing `SList s = new TailList();`?

Now, is static type of t still `TailList`?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: as @JonSkeet asked. there are different answer for different languages..

Comment: This syntax is incorrect for COBOL.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554379/virtual-tables-and-abstract-in-java

Comment: What do you mean by "Now" in the final question? If you've replaced all that code with `SList s = new TailList();` then `t` isn't even declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `SList s = new TailList();`, what happens is the following:

1. `new TailList()` is invoked, creating a new object which the constructor of `TailList` is run for. When the constructor finishes, an anonymous `TailList` reference is returned.
2. The anonymous `TailList` reference is assigned to `s`.

Since a `TailList` is inheriting from `SList`, you can also refer to it by that. The reference to the object doesn't change the object itself.

Imagine I put a trash bin somewhere, and then tell someone who doesn't know of that object being a trash bin that I put a "container" at that location. The trash bin is indeed a container, but that person only knows that it's a container. This doesn't change the fact that it's a trash bin, but the other person can't safely assume that he can put trash in there, or that it is scheduled to be emptied at any time, therefore he wouldn't know to invoke this functionality on the "container" that he is refering to.

So for instance, let's say we have the following code:

```
String s = "Hello there";
Object o = s;
```

`o` is now refering to a String object, but is treating it as an "object", it doesn't know that it has a length, or that it contains characters, even though it does.

`s` on the other hand, while still refering to the same object that `o` is refering to, knows that this object is a `String`, and can use `String` functionality on that object.

If we wanted to, we could assume that `o` is a `String` by a mechanism called "casting":

```
String s2 = (String)o;
```

We now refer to the object referenced by `o` as a `String`. All of this changes nothing for the object itself, it's all a mere change in reference. As if, for the previous analogy, the person who was told about the mysterious "container", will assume that the container is more specifically a "trash bin". We could also make a wrong assumption, that the container is a packaging container

```
Integer i = (Integer)o; // throws ClassCastException
```

Fortunately, when we assume wrongly in Java, we get a `ClassCastException`, unlike in real life where if you put your items into a trash bin while refering to it as a packaging container your belongings will be thrown to garbage.

Or perhaps, what is confusing you is that first assignment. Well, `new TailList()` part of `SList s = new TailList();` by itself is a static invocation of the constructor of `TailList`, and it will always return a `TailList` reference. The assignment that comes afterwards will still refer to the `TailList` object that was constructed by the invocation.

---

TL;DR

Yes, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The object will be instantiated as `TailList`, and the assignment won't change that. (It would be a neat trick if the language could change the implementation class on assignment ;) )

For example, you can always go

```
TailList t = new TailList();
Object o = t;
```

Does that make it more clear? The object is still the same implementation class. It' not going to change to an Object, even though we're referencing it that way.

You could always do a System.err.println(s.getClass().getName()) and see.

BTW this is actually polymorphism rather than inheritance, because you're referencing the object as a class higher in the hierarchy. Inheritance would be if you called `t.slistMethod()` without overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

In statically typed object-oriented languages, both objects and variables have an associated type.

The type of a variable (the 'static type') is specified by the programmer when declaring the variable. It never changes.

The type of the object referenced by the variable (the 'runtime type') must be either the same or a subtype of the variable's declared type. An object never changes type, but the variable may be assigned a different object of a different type.

The first snippet declares two variables, `s` of type `SList` and `t` of type `TailList`. It creates an object of type `TailList` and stores a reference to it in both variables.

The second snippet declares a variable `s` of type `SList`, creates an object of type `TailList`, and stores a reference to it in `s`.

The end result in both cases is that `s` contains a reference to an object of type `TailList`. The difference is that in the first snippet there is an additional reference to the object stored in variable `t` (which still has a static type of `TailList`).

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
TailList t = new TailList();
SList s = t;
```

The same as

```
SList s = new TailList();
```

Yes, except there's no separate reference of type `TailList` held to the new object, so you'll only be able to access methods from `SList` (unless you cast).