# Calling virtual functions in constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual

Consider the following program:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int m_nID;
public:
    Base()
    {
        m_nID = ClassID();
    }

    // ClassID returns a class-specific ID number
    virtual int ClassID() { return 1; }

    int GetID() { return m_nID; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
    }

    virtual int ClassID() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived cDerived;
    cout << cDerived.GetID(); 
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example,The derived id is surprisingly 1 instead of 2.I have already found a similar question regarding the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors).But what i don't understand is that if this is wrong,Then how are we supposed to identify a (derived) class member and use it?I mean suppose i want to dedicate a unique id or typename to each class (base class, the first derived class , the second derived class which is either a derivation of the base class or the second derived class and so on),In this regard how can i go on and act?
I think the correct way is that  i assign an id/name in the constructor upon the instantiation of any class object so that the type is known immediately.The above approach failes,What other options do i have in this regard?

Comment: after construction, `ClassID` returns what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: @BoPersson:Actually the question is pretty much different.I am not asking why it is happening,I am asking how can i get what i intent to achieve using this approach by other approaches.

Comment: @karolyHarvath:What if i am using a situation like this : void Foo(baseClass bar); and inside the Foo() function , based on the objects type, i have different operations.Suppose i have a Person class and two derived sub-classes named :Male and Female.There is a function such as this: void Foo(Person person){ if ( person.ClassID == 1 ) cout<<((Male)person).Type; else cout<<((Female)person).Type; } So does your solution work in this matter as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on what Karoly said, maybe you can just avoid using the class ID in the constructor, but after construction you can just do:

```
cout << cDerived.ClassID();
```

There is no reason to have two functions that return the same thing and there is no reason to waste memory by having your `int m_nID;` stored in every object.

Also, you should change your base class so that it says:

```
virtual int ClassID() = 0;
```

This *should* make it a compiler error if you try to call ClassID in your Base constructor, though I have not tried it.  Also, it will make Base be an abstract class, so you can't create new instances of it (which is good).

Comment: Thank you. What if i am using a situation like this :
void Foo(baseClass bar);
and inside the Foo() function , based on the objects type, i have different operations.Suppose i have a Person class and two derived sub-classes named :Male and Female.There is a function such as this:
void Foo(Person person){
if ( person.ClassID == 1 )
   cout<<((Male)person).Type;
else
    cout<<((Female)person).Type;
}
So does your solution work in this matter as well?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: You can't use any C++ object until it has been constructed. If you're still in the process of constructing the base-class subobject, then you can't use the derived-class object *because it hasn't been constructed yet.* (The vptr for the object currently under construction still points to the base-class vtable as long as you're inside the base-class constructor; it isn't updated until you get to the derived-class constructor.)

But then how does the base-class constructor determine whether it's being invoked for a regular object or a subobject? Well, the same way it tells any other random bit of information about the world: you have to tell it explicitly. For example:

```
struct Base {
    Base() { puts("I am a whole object!"); }
  protected:
    Base(bool is_subobject) { assert(is_subobject); puts("I'm only part of an object."); }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(): Base(/*is_subobject=*/true) { }
};
```

If you want to be really clever-trousers about it, you can use template metaprogramming:

```
struct Base {
    int m_nID;

    template<typename T>
    Base(T *)
    {
#ifdef UNSAFE
        // This breaks a lot of rules, but it will work in your case.
        // "this" is a Base, not a Derived, so the cast is undefined;
        // and if ClassID tried to use any non-static data members,
        // you'd be hosed anyway.
        m_nID = reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)->T::ClassID();
#else
        // This version is guaranteed to work in standard C++,
        // but you lose that nice virtual-ness that you worked
        // so hard for.
        m_nID = T::staticClassID();
#endif
    }

    virtual int ClassID() { return 1; }
    static int staticClassID() { return 1; }
    int GetID() { return m_nID; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(): Base(this) { }
    virtual int ClassID() { return 2; }
    static int staticClassID() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    Derived cDerived;
    std::cout << cDerived.GetID() << std::endl; // prints "2"
}
```

But as Dave S said while I was composing this answer... if your example is *all* you're doing, then you could just have a protected Base constructor that takes `int nID` as a parameter, and forget about the virtual methods altogether.

Comment: Please note that while it is the motivation behind that rule, the vtable/vptr is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Correct, vtable/vptr is just an implementation detail. But (as you can tell from my phrasing of the first sentence) I don't believe the rule "you can't access Derived from Base's constructor" is *motivated by* that particular implementation: instead it's motivated by the abstract notion of what it means to "construct" an object. From the implementation's POV, it would be simpler to set the vptr just once in `Derived::Derived`, but for *strictly theory-motivated* reasons the Standard requires that the implementation first set it to Base's vtable and then later reset it to Derived's.

Answer (score 2):

A `Derived` object contains a sub-object of type `Base`, the `Base` object exists "inside" the `Derived` object. Literally inside it. If you take the address of the object and the address of its `Base` sub-object the `Base` will be somewhere within the memory region occupied by the `Derived` object.

When you construct a `Derived` its constructor runs, and the first thing that happens is it constructs each of its base classes then each of its members.  So the first thing that happens when `Derived::Derived()` starts to execute is that `Base::Base()` executes. During that constructor, the object's *dynamic type* is not yet a `Derived` because it hasn't yet constructed the `Derived` parts. So when you call a virtual function during the `Base` constructor it finds the *final overrider* of the only object that has been constructed so far: the `Base` part.

Under the hood what happens is that when the `Base` constructor starts it sets the object's vptr to point to the vtable for `Base`, so it points to `Base`'s virtual functions.  After that completes and the `Derived` object constructor runs it updates the vptr to point to `Derived`'s vtable, so it refers to the functions that `Derived` overrides. So until the `Base` constructor has finished the object's vptr  only leads to pointers to the virtual functions defined by `Base`.

Once the `Derived` constructor has updated the vptr, calling the virtual functions will call the `Derived` overrides, so the answer to you question is to re-assign `m_nId` in the derived constructor, when it will call the overridden function and give you the derived class ID.