# C++ virtual method overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass {

    public:

    BaseClass() {
        init();
    }

    virtual ~BaseClass() {
        deinit();
    }

    virtual void init() {
        std::cout << "BaseClass::init()\n";
    }

    virtual void deinit() {
        std::cout << "BaseClass::deinit()\n";
    }

};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {

    public:

    virtual void init() {
        std::cout << "SubClass::init()\n";
    }

    virtual void deinit() {
        std::cout << "SubClass::deinit()\n";
    }

};

int main() {
    SubClass* cls = new SubClass;
    delete cls;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is `init()` and `deinit()` not properly overriden and the BaseClasses' methods are called instead of the SubClasses ones? What are the requirements to make it work?

```
BaseClass::init()
BaseClass::deinit()
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry for that. I didn't directly associate the problem with the constructor and destructor, which I guess was why I didn't find this question.

Comment: I guess the justification is that `SubClass`'s constructor is allowed to assume that `BaseClass` is entirely constructed when it is executing. Similar for the destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are calling a virtual method inside a constructor. While constructing Base class the derived one (SubClass) isn't still constructed, so actually it doesn't still exist.

It's generally a good practice to avoid calling virtual methods inside constructors.

Answer (score 5):

They are overridden just fine.

But you've invoked them from the *base constructor*, and when the base constructor is executing, the *derived* part of the object does not yet exist.

So this is a largely a safety feature, and it's mandated by the C++ standard.