# Virtual constructor and what happens calling virtual functions inside it

Tags: c++, oop, object

I have two questions and the answers I found here didn't totally satisfy me:

- Why declaring a constructor as virtual is meaningless?
- What happens when I call a virtual function from a constructor? Is the virtual table used too?

Comment: What does "get walked" mean?

Comment: This related question has some good information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: If _the answers you found here_ didn't satisfy you, please link to those answer and explain _why_ they didn't satisfy you, lest we repeat the mistake.

Comment: Its a repeated followup question in SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: this may be of interest: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-ctors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a constructor, the actual type of the (not yet existing) object is known for very sure. So calling a constructor will never be indirect. (Only virtual functions are called indirectly when called via a pointer / reference.)

```
BaseClass *x = new SubClass();
```

Calling a virtual function in a constructor doesn't do what you might expect. As the subclass hasn't been initialized yet, the virtual function on the final class can't be called (the v-table currently points to the class of the constructor currently being executed).

```
class BaseClass {
    BaseClass() {
        call();
    }
    virtual void call() {
        std::cout << "BaseClass!";
    }
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
    SubClass() : BaseClass()
    {
    }

    void call() {
        std::cout << "SubClass!";
    }
};
```

http://ideone.com/9aQVIc

Comment: Calling a virtual function from a constructor **is not** undefined behavior. It is perfectly defined in the standard to call the *final overrider* at the level of the type being constructed.

Comment: Corrected. I wasn't sure; I knew I'd remember it incorrectly. Now I remember. See my correction.

Comment: @David So just to clarify, if you had `class SubSubClass : public SubClass`, and you tried to call `call()` from `SubClass`'s constructor, it would call `SubClass::call()`?

Comment: Yes. When the constructor of a class is being called, it's the same as you were actually constructing an instance of exactly this class (and not a subclass). (Indeed, in this very moment, an instance of this class *is* being constructed. Nothing more until then. The constructor of a subclass always first calls the super class constructor.)

Comment: @JBentley: In C++ the type of an object changes during construction/destruction. At each level it is the type of the constructor/destructor being called. So yes, the code `call();` inside the constructor of `SubClass` won't be dispatched below the `SubClass` point in the hierarchy, even if the complete object being built is a `SubSubSub...Class`.

Comment: @David But when SubClass is being constructed, that means BaseClass is already constructed, so doesn't `call()` inside the `SubClass` constructor have two virtual functions to choose from (`SubClass::Call()` and `BaseClass::Call()`? I take your point that `call()` won't be dispatched *below* `SubClass`, but what about *above*?

Comment: Calling `call()` inside `SubClass` will then call `SubClass::call()`, yes.

Answer (score 3):

> Why declaring a constructor as virtual is meaningless?

Before the constructor is executed, the object does not exists, so there is no such thing as an *override*.

> What happens when I call a virtual function from a constructor? Is the virtual table used too?

It can. In most cases, if the call is directly performed from the constructor the compiler can skip the dynamic dispatch, as it knows what the final overrider is at this point. But it need not perform that optimization, and even if it can do that in the constructor directly, it cannot do it if you call a non-virtual function that in turn calls the virtual function. Because the non-virtual function might be called for objects of derived types it must use the virtual dispatch mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`Why declaring a constructor as virtual is meaningless`.

When the constructor is invoked the virtual table would not be available in the memory. Declaring something virtual in C++ means that it can be overridden by a sub-class of the current class, however the constructor is called when the objected is created, at that time you can not be creating a sub-class of the class you must be creating the class so there would never be any need to declare a constructor virtual.  Therefore, there is no such a thing as `virtual constructor` in C++.

`What happens when I call a virtual function from a constructor? Is the virtual table used too`

See [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html)  link about detailed explanation of this question.