# Is it possible to call a virtual method from an abstract class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

[image: class diagram]

Currently, I have the "lots of code" as noted in the diagram inside each child's constructor. My goal is to move it to the parent's constructor.

Comment: No, you should not call virtual methods from constructors or destructors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a virtual method from an abstract class constructor?

Technically it is possible, but it won't work as you expect, so **don't do it**, because the virtual table for derived classes has not been constructed yet.

The implementation *of the class being constructed* is going to be called when a virtual function is invoked from a constructor, and if the virtual function you are calling is pure, you get undefined behavior.

Per paragraph 10.4/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a
>   virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed)
>   from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.

Comment: Actually, the call to a pure virtual function is UB independently of whether the pure function has an implementation. I.e. Even if you deliberately provide a definition for the pure virtual function, calling it in a way that uses virtual dispatch (i.e. not `classname::`) still causes UB simply because the function is declared pure.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I edited the answer. I just learnt that a pure virtual function can have an implementation :) Thank you for correcting me

Comment: @AndyProwl Effective C++ 3rd Ed. Item 34 has a nice piece on implementation of pure virtual fucntions, but also notes that: "Apart from helping you impress your fellow programmers at a cocktail party, knowledge of this feature is generally of limited utility." Their main use is to provide impure virtual functions with a default implementation, and you have to call them with qualification like this: `derived_object->AbstractBase::draw()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to invoke **initializeFiles()** from the **FileContainer** constructor it will invoke **FileContainer::initializeFiles()**. This is because the constructor for the derived class has not been executed yet and therefore the v-table for the derived class has not been built.

Also if **FileContainer::initializeFiles()** is a pure-virtual function then you will get a crash.