# Implement a pure virtual function of a shared library and calling it in the lib

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, pure-virtual

I want to implement a pure virtual function of a shared lib and call it in a lib-function. This lib-function will be called in the constructor of the lib. The class which contains the pure virtual function is in an own namespace. It looks like this:

```
//shared lib class:
namespace A{
namespace B{

class SharedLibClass : public object{
public:
          SharedLibClass(){init();}

protected:
          virtual const object* func()const=0;
private:
          void init(){const object* obj=func();}

}
}//namespace B
}//namespace A

//implementation class using the shared lib:
class B : public A::B::SharedLibClass
{
protected:
          virtual void func(){return this;}
}
```

This are my classes. I can compile them without problems, but when I run it, Qt prints out the following error:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

I could imagine the problem is, that the parent class calls the virtual function before it is initialised or something like that. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The signature of `func()` in your derived class doesn't match the signature of `func()` in `SharedLibClass`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Also, your question doesn't have much to do with qt specifically.  It would probably be best to re-tag it "c++".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare function `void` and then return something from it. And you need to declare your function with exactly the same signature if you want to make it implementation of existing pure virtual function:

```
class B : public A::B::SharedLibClass {
protected:
  virtual const object* func() const { /* your implementation */ }
}
```

Any good compiler recognizes these issues in compilation time. Check error reporting, maybe something is wrong in your build process (maybe your file isn't compiled at all?).