# Overriden virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual, overriding, irrlicht

I've read a lot of things on the virtual functions, but I'm still not able to get something to work how I want.

Basically, I've got the following class:

```
class Body
{

    protected:
        scene::ISceneNode* Model;
        virtual void setModel();
    public:
        Body( core::vector3df Position, core::vector3df Rotation );
};


Body::Body( core::vector3df Position, core::vector3df Rotation )
{
    CurrentThrust = 0;
    setModel();
    Model->setPosition( Position );
    Model->setRotation( Rotation );
}

void Body::setModel()
{
    Model = Engine::Instance->GetSceneManager()->addCubeSceneNode();
    Model->setMaterialFlag( video::EMF_LIGHTING, false );
}
```

I am create new classes inheriting Body, and the idea is that I override "setModel()" in those classes, and the constructor will load my new model, instead of the default; like below

```
class Craft : public Body
{
    protected:
        virtual void setModel();
    public:
        Craft( core::vector3df Position, core::vector3df Rotation );
};

Craft::Craft( core::vector3df Position, core::vector3df Rotation ) : Body(Position, Rotation)
{
    // Other stuff
}

void Craft::setModel()
{
    Model = Engine::Instance->GetSceneManager()->addAnimatedMeshSceneNode( Engine::Instance->GetSceneManager()->getMesh("resource/X-17 Viper flying.obj") );  // addCubeSceneNode();
    Model->setMaterialFlag( video::EMF_LIGHTING, false );
    Model->setScale( core::vector3df(0.1f) );
}
```

However, it always creates a Cube model instead of my Viper mode when I create a new instance of Craft.

Is it possible to get virtual functions to work like I'm thinking? or do I need to just change my constructors to create the models in their respective classes?

Thanks

Comment: You should avoid calling virtual functions in a constructor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: How you create the objects? Please show us the usage, it's very important part in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get virtual functions to work like I'm thinking?

No. When you call one from a constructor, it's dispatched according to the class being initialised (`Body` in this case), not the final overrider (since that hasn't been initialised yet, so can't be accessed safely).

> or do I need to just change my constructors to create the models in their respective classes?

That's probably the simplest solution. I'd suggest passing the model as a constructor argument to `Body`. That way, it's impossible to forget to set it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Craft : public Body
{
    protected:
        void setModel();
    public:
        Craft( core::vector3df Position, core::vector3df Rotation );
};
```

Don't use the keyword `virtual` in the Class Craft.

Comment: `virtual` is valid. `override` is better if supported. And it is unrelated to OP problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like mathematician1975 pointed out, you should **never** use a virtual method inside a constructor or a destructor.

An object being built by a constructor cannot be considered of the constructor's class **until** the control flow leaves the constructor. Whenever you will call a virtual method inside of Craft's constructor, you will always end up invoking a Body's method.

Since setting your models means loading a mesh from a file, which is usually a quite expensive operation, I suggest that you do not do it until you really need it, i.e. whenever your model is requested. At this point, your virtual should behave like you expect it to.