# Pure virtual function call interesting cases

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:
   virtual void f() = 0;
   A(){f();}
};

void A::f() {
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
}

class B:public A{
 public:
    void f(){cout<<"B"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
 B b;
}
```

In this case I directly call the virtual function from constructor and get compiler warning which says:
warning: abstract virtual 'virtual void A::f()' called from constructor.
 But it executes without termination and prints A.

If I wrap the call of the function like this:

```
class A
{
  public:
   virtual void f() = 0;
   A(){g();}
   void g(){f();}
};

void A::f(){cout<<"A"<<endl;}

class B:public A{
 public:
    void f(){cout<<"B"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
 B b;
}
```

The compiler does not output any warning during compilation but it crushes at runtime with the following message:

```
pure virtual method called   
terminate called without active exception   
Abort
```

Can anybody explain the behavior of both of this cases?

Comment: Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **§ 10.4 Abstract classes [class.abstract] / p6**
>
> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call (10.3) to **a pure virtual** function directly or **indirectly** for the object being created (or destroyed) **from** such a **constructor** (or destructor) **is undefined**.

In brief: *The effect of making a call to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created from constructor is undefined.*

A call to pure virtual member functions cannot be used from a constructor or a destructor, no matter if the call is direct or indirect, because then you end up with an *undefined behavior*.

The only useful example of providing the implementation of a pure virtual function is when calling it from a derived class:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

void A::f()
{
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
}

struct B : A
{
    void f()
    {
        A::f();
        cout<<"B"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the compiler happens to save you by statically dispatching to `A::f()`, since it knows the static type of `A`. But it's quite right that this is horribly undefined behaviour and you shouldn't do it.

In the second case, the compiler does not statically dispatch to `A::f()` since the call is not in the constructor so it must dynamically dispatch it. Different ABIs handle pure virtual calls differently, but both MSVC and Itanium have a dedicated pure virtual call handler which is placed in the vtable to catch these events. This is what produces the error message you see.

Answer (score 1):

From a compiler's point of view, if you look at how the function f() is invoked:

- Case-1: A's ctor calls A-ctor => f() directly. Compiler knows precisely that this is the case and decides to issue a warning.
- Case-2: A's ctor calls A-ctor => g() => f(). There are entirely legitimate cases of calling f() from one of the class methods. Compiler can not say that this is illegal. The callgraph could have been from * => bar() => g() -> f(), meaning the type of the object is not known. Such paths being possible, makes dynamic dispatching necessary - leading to the runtime error.

As others pointed out, this is undefined usage and compilers only go so far in detecting and warning.

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined` behaviour means that the compiler does not have to handle the situation in any particularly defined manner.

Here your compiler, that knew the actual type of A in its constructor was able to inline in the pure virtual method rather than call it through the v-table. This is what would happen if the method were normal virtual, not pure virtual, and this would be defined behaviour.

Whilst it would be the behaviour too even via `g()`, the compiler did not do this for a pure virtual `f()` function. It doesn't have to.

The simple moral is do not invoke undefined behaviour, and if you want to call `f()` from the constructor do not make it pure virtual.

If you want to enforce your sub-classes to implement `f()`, do not call it from the constructor of A but give that function you want to call a different name. Preferably not virtual at all.