# Getter returns wrong value

Tags: c++, gdb, getter

I have a *special* problem. I'm working with other person's library (GPc) and there were some problems so I wanted to debug it. It seems that a simple getter is returning a wrong number. I've put a sanity-check print inside the getter and it's failing too. The getter is:

```
unsigned int getNumData() const {
  std::cout << "nData = " << nData << "\n";
  return nData;
}
```

Looks trivial, there's nothing which could go wrong. But, when I run it, it prints and returns a wrong number. I tried to debug that with gdb, see the result:

```
CGaussianNoise::initStoreage (this=0x7fffffffd2b0) at CNoise.cpp:313
313   int m = getNumData();
(gdb) s
CNoise::getNumData (this=0x7fffffffd2b0) at CNoise.h:161
161     std::cout << "nData = " << nData << "\n";
(gdb) p nData
$44 = 500
(gdb) n
nData = 0
162     return nData;
(gdb) n
163   }
(gdb) 
CGaussianNoise::initStoreage (this=0x7fffffffd2b0) at CNoise.cpp:314
314   int n = getOutputDim();
(gdb) p m
$45 = 0
(gdb) p nData
$46 = 500
```

The expected value of nData (according to the input) is 500. When I print it in gdb at the beginning of the getter, it seems OK. But the subsequence print using std::cout prints zero. And the returned value is zero, too... How is that possible?

Edit: the backtrack log of calls:

```
#0  CNoise::getNumData (this=0x7fffffffd2b0) at CNoise.h:161
#1  0x00000000004448ce in CGaussianNoise::initStoreage (this=0x7fffffffd2b0) at CNoise.cpp:313
#2  0x0000000000415bdc in CNoise::setTarget (this=0x7fffffffd2b0, vals=0x7fffffffd5c0)
at CNoise.h:194
#3  0x0000000000415cad in CGaussianNoise::CGaussianNoise (this=0x7fffffffd2b0, pyin=0x7fffffffd5c0)
at CNoise.h:320
#4  0x0000000000407fbc in CClgp::learn (this=0x7fffffffded0) at gp.cpp:369
#5  0x00000000004047cb in main (argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffe178) at gp.cpp:39
```

Edit2: I tried setting a rwatch on the memory where `nData` is stored and apparently it is once set but never read:

```
(gdb) info break
Num     Type            Disp Enb Address            What
...
9       read watchpoint keep y                      *0x7fffffffd420
10      hw watchpoint   keep y                      *0x7fffffffd420
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

Comment: `Looks trivial, there's nothing which could go wrong`  Unless your `CNoise` object is invalid.  Then all bets are off.

Comment: Is it set by someother thread to 0 ... I mean is there are some function which is modifying the nData from someother function by different thread. The right way to debug this issue is put the breakpoint where mdata is getting set .

Comment: Can you show the call to `CGaussianNoise::initStoreage` or perhaps the output `bt` from your debugger

Comment: Added the `bt` output, you can see the call at https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPc/blob/master/CNoise.h#l192

Comment: Are you sure that you're debugging in non-optimized build ?

Comment: We dont have enough information about HOW the code is used.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it is: `CCFLAGS = -ggdb -DDBG ... -O0 -g -fvar-tracking`

@Phong: There's not much to say, the whole thing is a machine-learning library, where I am trying to train a model using data from a file. In this particular bit a noise model is being created, the whole problem happens in ctor which just sets some flags and moves data back and forth...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could it be invalid in its own ctor?
nirajkumar: It's not multithreaded... anyway, the nData variable keeps its old (correct) value, at least gdb says so.

Comment: You're mangling your memory somewhere. Nothing trivial about that.

Comment: Gdb will just debug at that. You need to know what's happening between you calling the function and where. What is nData, and what does it represent? Is nData supposed to be changing? How would you know it's the wrong value?

Comment: @Poriferous I know what the correct value is because of the input data. It is just a number of datapoints, one of the dimensions of a data-storage matrix. I is set at the beginning of the constructor and not changed. And it was NOT changed, just the getter somehow hallucinated a zero instead of the real value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not exactly sure what the problem was, but this seems to have had something to do with it: [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors). After I cleaned all the calls to virtual methods from the `CGaussianNoise` constructor and moved the code directly inside (ugly code duplication though), it stopped doing these weird things...

Second possible explanation is that due to some problem with project's Makefile, one of the source files was compiled against different libraries and there was some conflict when linking them together, maybe a memory collision.