# Constructor calling virtual child function c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual-functions

Sorry bothering you with such an 'easy' question. I am trying to keep an overview over my code, so I want the following nice and clean, here is my condensed code:

```
class field_t {
public:
    field_t(fieldmap_t* fieldmap);
    ~field_t();
private:
    fieldmap* fieldmap;
    virtual int add_self_to_set(){  std::cout << "ERROR"; std::exit(0);   };
};

//constructor
field_t::field_t(fieldmap * fieldmap){
    this->fieldmap=fieldmap;
    this->add_self_to_list();
};



class area_t : public field_t {
public:
    // constructors are not inherited
    area_t(fieldmap_t* fieldmap) : field_t(fieldmap);
private:
    virtual int add_self_to_set(); //virtual because their will be further child classes.
};

int area_t::add_self_to_set() {
    this->fieldmap->area_list.insert(this);
    return 1;
};
```

Okay, this code should work (hope I missed no ; or so).
What is the problem? As the constructor of `area_t calls` `field_t::field_t(fieldmap)` it constructs (of course) a `field_t object`, which will say 'Error' and `exit()`;.

What I wanted is that the replaced `area_t::add_self_to_set()` function is called in the constructor (that's why I declared it virtual in `field_t`), but this doesn't work. This seems logic to me, but I don't know how to implement it properly. I need to insert the class into another list (a `std::set`) for each class type.

When I noticed the problems, I also thought about a different way. I could add the `add_self_to_list()` call to the `area_t` constructor by directly calling

```
area_t(fieldmap_t* fieldmap) : field_t(fieldmap){this->fieldmap->area_list.insert(this);};
```

and leave out all those virtual `add_self_to` list-stuff. But this leads to the next problem at the next child:

```
class entrance_t : public area_t{
    entrance_t(fieldmap_t* fieldmap) : area_t(fieldmap){this->fieldmap->entrance_list.insert(this);};
};
```

Of course I do not want `entrance_t` to appear in the `are_list`!
Similar problem for the constructors.

Any ideas?? Thanks a lot for your time in advance. I guess I don't need to say, that I am beginner ^^.

Greets

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot mark it as answered, but the hint from TartanLlama lead me to http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom.html what matched my question perfectly. A big 'Thank you' for your help!