# Call derived method from base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to do the following:

```
void do_stuff(Base* base_ptr) {
   // here I need the overridden methods
   base_ptr->init();
}

class Base {
   Base() {
     do_stuff(this);
   }
   virtual void init() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
   virtual void init() override {
      // Derived specific init
   }
}
```

But all I get are calls to Base::init(), is it even possible to do what I intend?

Comment: How does Base have any knowledge of Derived?

Comment: I think the call to `new Derived` is implied here as what should be run.

Comment: Are you allowed to call virtual functions from the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a virtual function from within the constructor!

Duplicated of -> [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: Thanks, is it ok to "register" the object in some global container in the base constructor? The access to the virtual methods would happen at a later point.