# Method called in creator is called from base class but not from derived class

Tags: c++

Maybe this was covered in some other topic. But I did not find any satisfactory answer. Could somebody explain me following. I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
   Base() {
      foo();
   }

   virtual void foo() { 
      std::cout << "Base::foo()" << std::endl; 
   }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   Derived(): Base() {}

   virtual void foo() { 
      std::cout << "Derived::foo()" << std::endl; 
   }
};

int main() {
   Derived* p = new Derived();
}
```

Now my question is why does the Base creator calls foo method which is in the Base and not in the Derived class, although it is overridden in the Derived class?

Comment: `Derived`'s part is not yet constructed.

Comment: Related to [calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad pratice to call virtual functions inside of constructor. I just give simple example, which will show disadvantages of this approach (Note: It is about c++ (other languages can use different implementation).

Order of calling constructors in your code is:

1) Base

2) Derived

At the moment of calling Base constructor, member specified in Derived class is not created. Suppose, you can use function, overrided in Derived class. In this case you can invoke functions, which will have access to NOT CREATED DATA (note, at the moment Derived class is not created). Obviously, it is too dangerous. At that point it seems logicaly to call function, which can work with created data (in this case it is data of Base class)

Answer (score 2):

Inside a constructor, the class of the object being constructed is that of the class to which the constructor belongs. In this case, inside the `Base` constructor, the class of the object being constructed is `Base`. You cannot make virtual calls from inside a constructor, they are all statically resolved.

It would be quite dangerous to allow virtual calls inside a constructor. Inside a constructor, the execution order is:

- Base class(es) constructor(s)
- Data member constructors, in the order the data members are declared in the class definition
- Constructor body

Of course, this is recursive: the execution order inside each base class constructor is the same.

Now, imagine what would happen if `Derived::foo()` used data members defined in `Derived`. Those data members would not have been constructed yet when the `Base` constructor is executed. What would happen in that case? The dreaded undefined behaviour, of course.

For this reason, calling virtual functions inside a constructor is not generally a good idea. As you can see, the function called may not be the one expected (since there is actually no virtual call); but making that virtual call might easily lead into undefined behaviour, which is always bad.

Answer (score 1):

Frome [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors):

> Only the *local* definitions are used – and no calls are made to overriding functions to avoid touching the derived class part of the object.

In *'ctors* only *local* definition are used (local in sense of scope of that class).

That is done in order to avoid touching derived class part of the object which are potentially not initialized yet.

The example is self-explanatory:

```
 class B {
    public:
        B(const string& ss) { cout << "B constructor\n"; f(ss); }
        virtual void f(const string&) { cout << "B::f\n";}
    };

 class D : public B {
    public:
        D(const string & ss) :B(ss) { cout << "D constructor\n";}
        void f(const string& ss) { cout << "D::f\n"; s = ss; }
    private:
        string s;
    };
```

If `D::f` was called in the constructor `B::B` then it would try to assign a value to an uninitialized `string s` (because the constructor `D::D` wouldn't called yet).

That's why *C++* standard *behaviour* has been so defined.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual function calls in C++ are resolved in accordance with the *dynamic* type of the object used in the call (this is what differentiates virtual functions from non-virtual ones).

When the constructor (or destructor) of class `Base` is active, the dynamic type of the object is always considered to be `Base`, even if that `Base` object is "embedded" into some larger derived object (like `Derived` in your case). For this reason all virtual calls made while `Base`'s constructor is active will resolve to the members of `Base`.

Note that the virtual call mechanism is not formally disabled in this case. (It is not correct to claim that virtual calls made from constructors are resolved "statically"). The virtual call mechanism still works as usual. It is just that the hierarchy tree is "capped"/"trimmed" at the class whose constructor is currently active.

The rationale behind this rule is pretty natural: while `Base` constructor is active, `Derived` is not constructed yet. Accessing any members of `Derived` would be dangerous. Moreover, trying to work around this restriction (which is possible) usually leads to undefined behavior. The same logic symmetrically applies to destructors.