# C++ virtual method not called as expected

Tags: c#, c++, oop, inheritance

I'm fiddling around with proper overriding of virtual methods. I chain some constructors and in the base class constructor I call a virtual method.

Call chain should be as followed:

```
B(p)->A(p)->B.foo(p)
```

Call chain is in C++:

```
B(p)->A(p)->A.foo(p)
```

Call chain is in C#:

```
B(p)->A(p)->B.foo(p)
```

So in other words, in C# behaviour is like expected, in C++ it isn't.

C++ Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A {
public:
  A();
  A(int);

  virtual void foo(int s);
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B();
  B(int s) : A(s) {};

  virtual void foo(int s) override;
};

A::A() {
  std::printf("A\r\n");
};

A::A(int s) : A() {
  std::printf("A: %d\r\n", s);
  foo(s);
};

void A::foo(int s) {
  std::printf("A::foo(%d)\r\n", s);
}

B::B() : A(){
  std::printf("B\r\n");
};

void B::foo(int s) {
  std::printf("B::foo(%d)\r\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  B b(2);
}
```

Output:

```
A
A: 2
A::foo(2)
```

C# Code:

```
using System;

namespace demo {
class A{
  public A() {
    Console.WriteLine("A");
  }

  public A(int s) : this(){
    Console.WriteLine("A: " + s.ToString());
    foo(s);
  }

  public virtual void foo(int s) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A:foo({0})", s));
  }
}

class B : A{
  public B() : base() {
    Console.WriteLine("B");
  }

  public B(int s) : base(s) {
  }

  public override void foo(int s) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("B:foo({0})", s));
  }
}

  static class Run {
    static void Main() {
      new B(2);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
A: 2
B::foo(2)
```

Why isn't the overriden method of class B called in C++? How do I have to override it correctly?

Comment: Virtual dispatching doesnt work until the constructors are finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: You've said the outputs are the same for C++ and C#. Did you mean in C# it calls B::foo(2)?

Comment: no, the outputs are not the same, C# behaves as expected, C++ not. I added the outputs to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way C++ works. Virtual functions do not behave virtually during object construction and destruction.

Comment: why not? they do :) , its just they use vtables that are not expected by the author