# C++ How to call subclass method from method in superclass?

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to call a method from the subclass by calling a method in the super class.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Robot {
  public:
    Robot() {
      printf("Robot init\n");
      update();
    }
    virtual void update() {
      printf("Robot update\n");
    }
};

class Terminator: public Robot {
  public: 
    Terminator(): Robot() {
      printf("Terminator init\n");
    }
    virtual void update() {
      printf("Terminator update\n");
    }
};

int main() {

  Terminator terminator;
  Robot* robot = &terminator;
}
```

This code returns (with annotation)

```
Robot init
Robot update       <--- not what I want
Terminator init
```

How can I make it return

```
Robot init
Terminator update  <--- what I want
Terminator init
```

using `update` in the robot the robot constructor?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: @marcinj Why don't you vote to close as a dup?