# c++: inherit constructor, but change by editing methods called within constructor

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a base class,

```
struct X{
     std::container<class> A;
     std::container<class> B;

     void do_this(...){...};
     void do_that(...){...};

     X(classC something){
          do_this(...);
          do_that(...);
     }
}
```

And I want to create a descendant, but I need to only change a couple of lines in one of the methods called in the constructor:

```
struct Y:X{
    void do_this(...){
         // make my changes
    }
}
```

Now, when I call `Y(classC input)`, I should get my `Y` struct as intended, right?

---

How would I do this in C++?

Comment: I believe you want a [`virtual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) function, but you [should avoid calling virtual functions in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: Can those members be placed in another class?

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think so? path of least resistance here is just for me to redo the constructor.  If it is a difficult question to answer, and I need to use a lot of magic words in the code, then I'll just respect the downvote and move along

Comment: As long as `Y` inherits from `X` and `X` doesn't have a default constructor you should call it explicitly.

Comment: It's not difficult to answer, and I didn't downvote. I just want to know about your constraints.

Comment: @StoryTeller oh, ok, yeah, the members reference items within the class, so they can't come out...or they could, but it would defeat the purpose, as I would be creating a lot of functions--would rather just copy paste at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, when I call Y(classC input), I should get my Y struct as intended, right?

Wrong. Inheriting a constructor doesn't mean its body is recreated with the function calls substituted by the ones you overload. It means that to construct a `Y` it is sufficient to construct the `X` sub-object explicitly via that c'tor. So rather than hassling you with forwarding stuff, you pull the appropriate c'tor into `Y` to be used.

This means, same c'tor body. And everything else that is `Y` specific will be default initialized.

> How would I do this in C++?

Simply put, you can't do it easily. Unless you mess around with dark template magic, `X::X` will always call `X::do_this`. You could also move `do_this` to some other class, and use *that* one polymorphically, but as you mentioned, this isn't an option.

If you want to **add a call** to `Y::do_this`, then write a c'tor for `Y`. But it won't replace the call to `X::do_this`, it will happen afterwards. That's the C++ object model.

Comment: Ok, great--thanks man.  Wanted to avoid repeating the code, but sounds like it has to happen.

Comment: @bordeo - There's no silver bullet. Not so long as you limit yourself purely to c'tors and nothing more complex.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by c'tor?

Comment: @bordeo - Shorthand for "constructor".

Answer (score 1):

As long as class `Y` inherits from class `X` and class `X` doesn't have a default constructor you must call its overloaded version explicitly in the overloaded class (Y):

```
class X{
    public:
        X(int _x) : x(_x){};
    private:
        int x;
};

class Y : public X{
    public:
        Y() : X(0){} // important
};


int main() {

    Y y; // if you remove the default constructor of Y you'll get an error here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if I overload the method used in the constructor, I will get my Y?

Answer (score 1):

This is tough, because the only good method would be to use `virtual` functions. This is however not feasible here, because `virtual` methods in constructors are resolved statically. This means, that if you have class `A` and class `B : A` and both of them have implemented virtual function `foo`, when you call `foo` in base class constructor it will always use base class implementation.

The one method is to use it like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(whatever) { }
    virtual void initialize() {
        // base class impl
    }
};
class B : public A{
public:
    // if no base default ctor, use
    // B(whatever)
    //     : A(whatever)
    B(whatever) {
    }
    virtual void initialize() override {
        // derived class impl
    }
};

template <typename T> // constraint it if you want.
T createObject() {
    T object;
    object.initialize(); // resolved dynamically
}
```

Comment: ah, I see what you are saying! makes sense that it wouldn't work, if that is how it is designed