# When is the vptr initialized for derived classes?

Tags: c++

Recently,I've been reading "inside the c++ object model". It says that the vptr initializes after calling the base class's constructor. So I ran a test:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    virtual int vfunc() {
        return 1;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A(vfunc()) {
    }

    virtual int vfunc() {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
2
```

My question is, does class B set its vptr first before calling the base class A's constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: You don't have any call through vptr in your code. `cs` is a normal "method" of your B class.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. cs() is actually vfunc(). I've already edited the question.

Comment: You also made your `A` class constructor private

Comment: Sorry, another mistake I've made.

Comment: That actually doesn't matter, if you have a call to a virtual function in the constructor it won't use vptr to call it, it will use the one it can find w/o any vptr magic. Thus you have a simple direct call to `B::vfunc` which is UB, btw. Because you are not allowed to call member functions until its parents' ctors are completed.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is **no**. If `vptr` would be set before the parent constructor gets executed it would mean that that constructor would overwrite it.

As to the behavior you see in your code: any call to the virtual function for the object under construction inside its constructor is resolved w/o `vptr`. So your code is actually an equivalent to:

```
B() : A(B::vfunc()) {
    }
```

There is no virtual call. Relevant standard wording([class.cdtor]p3):

> Member functions, including virtual functions (13.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (15.6.2). When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction,
>   the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard says nothing about `vptr` or setting it.

However, the Standard does say that `virtual` calls depend on the type of the object **at the moment of the call**. In the constructor of `A`, the type is `A`, in the constructor of `B` the type is `B`. But that's inside the body of constructor. Since the initializer list also includes initialization of the base classes, at the time the initializer list of `B::B()` begins to execute the object does not have **any** type yet.

Formally:

> § 12.6.2.13: Member functions (including virtual member functions,
>   10.3) can be called for an object under construction. [...] However, if these operations are performed in a ctor-initializer (or in a function
>   called directly or indirectly from a ctor-initializer) before all the
>   mem-initializers for base classes have completed, the result of the
>   operation is **undefined**.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

during class construction/destruction any virtual call would be resolved as if the class' override is final override. I'm almost 100% sure this behavior is standard mandated, but you better check this out. Example:

http://cpp.sh/2gyz5

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
    public:
    virtual void f1(){
        std::cout<<"1A"<<std::endl;
    }
    virtual void f2(){
        std::cout<<"2A"<<std::endl;
    }
    A(){
        f1();
    }
    virtual ~A(){
        f1();
    }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    virtual void f1(){
        std::cout<<"1B"<<std::endl;
    }
    virtual void f2(){
        std::cout<<"2B"<<std::endl;
    }
    B():A(){
        f2();
    }
    ~B(){
        f2();
    }
};

class C: public B{
    public:
    virtual void f1(){
        std::cout<<"1C"<<std::endl;
    }
    virtual void f2(){
        std::cout<<"2C"<<std::endl;
    }
    C():B(){
        f2();
    }
    ~C(){}
};

int main(){
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

it will produce output

```
1A
2B
2C
2B
1A
```

because call sequence would be
    C::C B::B A::A A::f1 B::f2 C::f2 C::~C B::~B B::~f2 A::~A A::f1