# Override derived template class method in C++11/14

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14

I need to override the method `createT()` of a `Base` template class with the one in a `Derived` template class with a different number of input parameters. I've developed this very simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Helper
{
public:
  Helper(std::string s): _s(s)
  {}

  void display()
  {
     std::cout << _s << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::string _s;
};

class Helper2
{
public:
  Helper2(std::string s, int i):
    _s(s), _i(i)
  {}

  void display()
  {
    std::cout << _s << " + " << std::to_string(_i) << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::string _s;
  int _i;
};

template<class T> class Base
{
public:
  Base()
  {
    _pTBase = createT();
  }

  void test()
  {
    _pTBase->display();
  }

protected:
  /// Subclasses can override this method.
  virtual T* createT()
  {
    return new T("### BASE ###");
  }

private:
 T* _pTBase;

}; //template<class T> class Base


template<class T> class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
  Derived() : Base<T>()
  {
    _pTDerived = createT();
  }

  void test()
  {
    _pTDerived->display();
  }

protected:
  virtual T* createT()
  {
    return new T("### DERIVED ###", 5);
  }

private:

 T* _pTDerived;

}; //template<class T> class Derived : public Base<T>


int main()
{
  Derived<Helper2> a;

  a.test();

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile I receive this message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Helper2::Helper2(const char [13])’
     return new T("### BASE ###");
                                ^
```

It seems that the compiler cannot use the `createT()` method in the derived class.

Of course everything works correctly if I use the `Base` class with the `Helper` (not the `Helper2`) class.

What's the right way to solve this situation?

Comment: @datell That's not the problem in this case.

Comment: Yes. it is the same problem. You cannot call virtual functions pointing to derived classes that has not been constructed yet.

Answer (score 2):

When `a` is constructed, first the `Base<Helper2>` base object is constructed.  That constructor will call `Base::createT`, which requires `Helper2` to have a constructor that takes one parameter.  Since that doesn't exist, you get the compilation error.

When you construct a `Derived<Helper>` object, you get two `Helper` objects created:  one by `Base`'s constructor, stored in `_pTBase`, and one by `Derived<Helper>`'s constructor, stored in `_pTDerived`.

One way to fix this is to have the derived class call a ([non-virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)) `Create` function, then pass the returned pointer to the base class constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that the **Base** class is part of an external library that I cannot modify and overriding the method **Base::createT** is the only way to use it.

Comment: If this is the case, then its unlikely they are expecting you to overide a virtual function that they call in the base constructor. What is the external library?

Comment: Tha external library is POCO. The problem was also shown by @chris [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872709/poco-custom-socketacceptor) but he hasn't received a response yet.