# How to deal with `init()` member function inside constructor and with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Imagine these classes:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() : Base(false)
    { }
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void init()
    {
        cout << "Base::init" << endl;
        check();
        // ...
    }

    virtual void check()
    {
        cout << "Base::check" << endl;
        // ...
    }
protected:
    Base(bool skip_init)
    {
        cout << "Base::Base" << endl;
        if (!skip_init) init();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base(true)
    {
        cout << "Derived::Derived" << endl;
        init();
    }
    virtual ~Derived() = default;

    void init()
    {
        cout << "Derived::init" << endl;
        Base::init();
        // ...
    }

    virtual void check() override
    {
        cout << "Derived::check" << endl;
        Base::check();
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then constructing a `Derived` instance would result in

```
Base::Base
Derived::Derived
Derived::init
Base::init
Derived::check
Base::check
```

which is exactly what I want to achieve.
It satisfies these requirements:

- `Base` defines `init()` with operations common to all subclasses and should be used right after construction of *whole* object (and *only* there)
- `init()` can contain `virtual` functions inside, but since it should be called only in the final constructor, it should not cause any harm
- `check()` can be called any time, not only from `init()` (it should be independent from it), and should always perform all checking, not only those related to the subclass

My best approach so far, as above, was to use protected constructor with flag that avoids calling "incomplete" `Base::init()` because of virtual functions do not work in superclass constructor. (Without the flag, `Base::check()` would be called twice.)

My question is: isn't there a better, preferably somehow standard technique, that deals with calling virtual routines *after whole object* is initialized (pardon for vague terminology)? And of course without requiring users to call `init()` explicitly (it should stay protected).

One possible use case (mine): `Base` stands for e.g. an array of general mathematical formulas which must satisfy several constraints. `Derived` (i.a.) restricts these constraints, add some, can override some particular checks, but mostly still use these from `Base`. E.g. `Base::check_formulas()` applies `check_formula(f)` to every `f`, and `Derived` needs to override only `check_formula` function.

**EDIT**:

As it is better to avoid virtual functions inside constructors at all, it appears not to be possible to achieve virtual function call from within the object itself, so the object must be constructed "externally" before calling these functions.

Both @StoryTeller and @Caleth suggests deal with this issue, either via dynamic allocation and pointer, or via a function with stack allocation (which is OK with move semantics).

Both of them inspired me to this solution, which is similar to @Caleth's as I found it more simple and straightforward:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T create(Args&&... args)
{
    T t(forward<Args>(args)...);
    t.init();
    return t;
}

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& rhs) = default;
    Base(Base&& rhs) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base& rhs) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&& rhs) = default;

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    friend T create(Args&&... args);
protected:
    Base() : _arg(0)
    {
        cout << "Base::Base()" << endl;
    }

    Base(int arg) : _arg(arg)
    {
        cout << "Base::Base(int)" << endl;
    }

    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << "Base::init" << endl;
        check();
        // ...
    }

    virtual void check()
    {
        cout << "Base::check" << endl;
        // ...
    }
private:
    int _arg;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual ~Derived() = default;

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    friend T create(Args&&... args);
protected:
    Derived() : Base()
    {
        cout << "Derived::Derived()" << endl;
    }

    Derived(int arg) : Base(arg)
    {
        cout << "Derived::Derived(int)" << endl;
    }

    void init() override
    {
        cout << "Derived::init" << endl;
        Base::init();
        // ...
    }

    void check() override
    {
        cout << "Derived::check" << endl;
        Base::check();
        // ...
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
cout << endl << "Base() ..." << endl;
Base b1 = create<Base>();
cout << endl << "Base(int) ..." << endl;
Base b2 = create<Base>(5);
cout << endl << "Derived() ..." << endl;
Derived d1 = create<Derived>();
cout << endl << "Derived(int) ..." << endl;
Derived d2 = create<Derived>(10);
```

Output:

```
Base() ...
Base::Base()
Base::init
Base::check

Base(int) ...
Base::Base(int)
Base::init
Base::check

Derived() ...
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Derived::init
Base::init
Derived::check
Base::check

Derived(int) ...
Base::Base(int)
Derived::Derived(int)
Derived::init
Base::init
Derived::check
Base::check
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: you do call `init()` from the `Base` constructor before the whole object is constructed

Comment: `init()` functions are a scaled down version of the devil. Why not use constructors which is what they are designed for?

Comment: [OT]: having `Derived::check` before `Derived::init` as expected behavior is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have any public constructor, but instead have (friend) `make_base` and `make_derived` factory functions, which call `init` on a fully constructed object.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base &) = default;
    Base(Base &&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base &) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base &&) = default;

    friend Base make_base() { Base b; b.init(); return b; } 

protected:
    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << "Base::init" << endl;
        check();
        // ...
    }

    virtual void check()
    {
        cout << "Base::check" << endl;
        // ...
    }

    Base()
    {
        cout << "Base::Base" << endl;
    }
};


class Derived : public Base {
    friend Derived make_derived() { Derived b; b.init(); return b; }
protected:
    Derived() : Base()
    {
        cout << "Derived::Derived" << endl;
    }

    void init() override
    {
        Base::init();
        cout << "Derived::init" << endl;
        // ...
    }

    void check() override
    {
        Base::check();
        cout << "Derived::check" << endl;
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Better idea how to solve that problem with virtual function calls yeah.

Comment: I would like to stick to constructors. I got an "idea" to rename classes to e.g. `Base_` and `Derived_` and the friend functions to `Base` and `Derived`, so that they would act as constructors; but I guess it is bad idea as these identifiers would not represent type names but function names, etc. ..

Comment: @TomášKolárik "I would like to stick to constructors" why? This is just as encapsulated, and StoryTeller's is even more so.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I just won't let anyone construct those objects directly. If their initialization is brittle, there should be another object holding them, and initializing them in its own constructor. I'd do it via the key-pass idiom.

```
class BaseHolder;
class Base {
private:
    void init() {
      // do more things
    }
    friend class BaseHolder;
protected:
    class BuildToken {
        explicit BuildToken() {}
        friend class BaseHolder;
    };
    Base(BuildToken) {
      // do your thing.
    }
};

template<typename>
struct MakeType{};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr MakeType<T> make{};

class BaseHolder {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> managed;
public:
    template<typename T>
    BaseHolder(MakeType<T>) : managed(new T(Base::BuildToken())) {
      managed->init();
    }
};
```

Now no derived class may call `init` itself, nor may it be called anywhere besides by `Base` and `BaseHolder`. All a derived class has to do is define a c'tor that accepts a `BuildToken` and forwards it to the base. However, derived classes cannot default initialize `BuildToken` objects themselves, they can only copy them to forward onto their base. The only place the token can be created is in `BaseHolder`. This is also the only place where `init` will be called at the proper time.

The utility `MakeType` is there for making `BaseHolder` declaration easier on the eyes, to look like this:

```
BaseHolder item(make<Derived>);
```

Answer (score 1):

> - `init()` can contain **virtual functions inside**, but since it should be called only in the final constructor, it should not cause
>     any harm.

Even if it's called through the *final constructor* any of the vtables for calling these virtual functions aren't initialized at that point.

So you can't guarantee the correct intended behavior.

See more elaborations of the problem here please:

- [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: I think that the execution is correct in the result, as `Derived` is supposed to be the only and last one from the hierarchy that calls it and virtual mechanism is not necessary at all. But I agree that it is not clean.