# Can virtual function be called inside member initializer lists?

Tags: c++

effective c++ item 9

Can function createLogString be virtual?

```
class BuyTransaction: public Transaction {  
　public:  
　　BuyTransaction( parameters ):Transaction(createLogString(parameters)) { ... }
　　...   
　private:  
　　static std::string createLogString( parameters );  
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

Comment: It's not allowed to have both `static` and `virtual`, so here we all assume that you want to change the static function into a virtual function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be virtual (instead of static). It will still be statically bound during construction however, and not dispatched dynamically.

The only point to making it virtual is if it is also used in some other member of the class (that is not a constructor/destructor) and a deriving class can possibly override it to do something useful for those members. However, that starts having the faint traces of a design smell.

Scott's advice of "Never call virtual functions during construction or destruction" stems from the fact that it rarely if ever accomplishes anything useful.

Comment: So it will make no sense if we implement the virtual function in some  child class of BuyTransaction because BuyTransaction's member initializer list will still call its own createLogString when initializing that child class?

Comment: @BowenFu - Exactly.

Comment: I prefer this answer than the one linked as duplicate which is too lengthy and too strict. Inside a constructor, all member function call are equivalent to a qualified call.

Comment: *Never call virtual functions during construction or destruction*. Clang static analyzer even has checks to spot these behaviors.

Comment: Um... but it's `static`? Or do OP and yourself mean replacing `static` with `virtual`?

Comment: @Quentin - That's how I understood the question. Didn't really give it a second thought, tbh.

Comment: Fair enough. --

Comment: Won't it be bound to the type of the constructor's init list you call the function? As in, if there is a parent class that declares it virtual, and the current class overrides it, the override will be called, no? As @Oliv says in his/her comment.

Comment: @rubenvb - That's what "bound statically" meant. Name lookup is based on scope.