# Calling decorated function internally in concrete implementation of abstract class

Tags: c++, class, decorator

I have one more question about decoration of c++ classes. With decorators I change `virtual int get()` function. But in NPC class I also call the `get()` function to get some values for calculation. Is there a way to call Elite::get() inside NPC. I want to get 100 and not 10. Thank you.

```
class AbstractNPC {
public:
    virtual int get() = 0;
};

class NPC: public AbstractNPC {
public:
    NPC() { }
    int get(){ return 10; }
    calc(){ int i = get(); }
};

class NPCDecorator: public AbstractNPC {
private:
    AbstractNPC * npc;
public:
    NPCDecorator(AbstractNPC *n) { npc = n; }
    int get() { npc->get(); }
};

class Elite: public NPCDecorator {
public:
    Elite(AbstractNPC *n): NPCDecorator(n) { }
    int get() { return 100; }
};
```

Or is there a better way? Maybe the use of function pointers?

Comment: The only way I see is to derive Elite or NPCDecorator from NPC. Because with current class hierarchy an object cannot have NPC and Elite type as the same time.

Comment: And code doesn't compile, so please fix it. The return type of NPC::get and NPC:calc is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use inheritance:

```
class Elite: public NPC {
public:
    int get() { return 100; }
};
```

[See it online!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pDb52n0cEaNkOo01)

---

`get()` method is polymorphic. This means compiler will know whether it should call `Elite::get` or `NPC::get`, no matter where you call it. You have to be careful about [using virtual methods in constructors or destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors), but otherwise it should work just right.

Comment: Thank you. Elite is a Decorator which can be set dynamically by runtime, so I think I have to give up the concept of decorations in this example.

Comment: Inheritance is usually more [simple and stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) than any design pattern. If you don't have any additional constraints, it's probably good - you can easily use `Elite` in place of `NPC`, you don't need boilerplate code. If you have additional constraints (like you need to call `get()` from within constructor), then you need to think of something else.