# OOP - How to call child method at parent class

Tags: c++, oop, virtual

I am trying to call virtual method at the constructer of parent class and I want to that of child methods. Let me explain:

I need to read words from line by line from a text file and insert them a search tree one by one. I have tree child classes: `DictionaryBST`,`DictionaryAVLTree`,`Dictionary23Tree`. I implemented their own insert methods.

Here the header code of my parent class which is DictionarySearchTree:

```cpp
class DictionarySearchTree {
public:

    DictionarySearchTree();
    DictionarySearchTree(string dictionaryFile);
    virtual ~DictionarySearchTree();
    virtual void insert(string word);
    virtual void search(string word, int& numComparisons, bool& found) const;
    virtual void search(string queryFile, string outputFile) const;
    virtual void inorderTraversal();

protected:
    TreeNode* root;
    int size;

    void searchNode(TreeNode* node, string word, int& numComparisons, bool& found) const;
    void virtual insertNode(TreeNode*& node, string word);
    void postTraversalDeletation(TreeNode*& node);
    void inorder(TreeNode* node);
    void getHeight(TreeNode* node, int& height);
};
```

Here is the constructer:

```cpp
DictionarySearchTree::DictionarySearchTree(string dictionaryFile) {

    root = NULL;
    size = 0;
    
    istringstream stream;
    ifstream infile;
    string line;
    infile.open(dictionaryFile);

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        insert(line);    // This methods should call child's ones.
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

My main method:

```cpp
int main() {
    DictionarySearchTree* tree = new DictionaryBST("./dictionary.txt");
    DictionarySearchTree* avlTree = new DictionaryAVLTree("./dictionary.txt");
    DictionarySearchTree* twoThreeTree = new Dictionary23Tree("./dictonary.txt");
}
```

I don't want to write constructer methods to each one, as well. Can some help me?

Comment: @yano `dynamic_cast`ing the `this` pointer won't work inside the base class's constructor and destructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I was fuzzy on that and remembered when I read your answer. The child constructor hasn't finished, makes sense.

Comment: Actually, I understood what you mean and it seems logical. But I want to know ,as well, that is there a way to do it like what I explain?

Comment: The parent class has no idea of child methods, nor how many children there are.  There could be zero children.  The parent can't be selective and discern which child called it.

Comment: @FurkanCalik No, it is not possible like you want, because the child portion of the `this` object simply does not exist yet, it hasn't even started being constructed yet, while the parent constructor is running, thus you can't call child methods on it.  You have to wait until the child constructor is running/exited before you can call any child methods on the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `virtual` functions in a constructor or destructor. The reason for this is that during the constructor of `DictionarySearchTree`, the runtime type of the current object `this` *is always* `DictionarySearchTree` and never any more derived type. This means that `virtual` function calls made during the constructor will always be bound to those defined or inherited by `DictionarySearchTree`, and nothing more. There are good reasons for this and they're discussed further [in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors)

The best thing in your case would be to populate the dataset after constructing the most-derived object. For example, you could add a `void populate(string dictionaryFile)` member function to `DictionarySearchTree` that calls all the `virtual` member functions you want. Then, importantly, call this `populate()` function *after* you have constructed the most derived object, as a separate step.

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<DictionarySearchTree> tree = std::make_unique<DictionaryBST>();
    std::unique_ptr<DictionarySearchTree> avlTree = std::make_unique<DictionaryAVLTree>();
    std::unique_ptr<DictionarySearchTree> twoThreeTree = std::make_unique<Dictionary23Tree>();

    tree.populate("./dictionary.txt");
    avlTree.populate("./dictionary.txt");
    twoThreeTree.populate("./dictionary.txt");
}
```

Note that smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` should be prefered over raw owning pointers for dynamic memory management.

The [ISO C++ FAQ on Strange Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors) also discusses this issue and suggests two-phase initialization as I've shown here as a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

A base class constructor (and destructor) cannot call virtual methods of a derived class.

In the base class constructor, the derived class portion of the object has not been constructed yet.

In the base class destructor, the derived class portion of the object has already been destroyed.

In both cases, the `this` pointer is pointing at the base class portion of the object, not the derived portion. If there is a vtable involved (which is usually the case in polymorphism, but that is not guaranteed by the C++ standard), it is pointing at the base class's vtable, not the derived class's vtable.

You need to rethink your design. For instance, by moving the tree-management methods into a separate container class that manages a pointer to the actual tree and can then create instances of your polymorphic classes as needed. Such as by taking in a template parameter to specify the class type of the tree. Or determining the class type to use based on the contents of the text file. Etc.