# Call a derived member function from parent class

Tags: c++, multithreading, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I need to call `B::f()` in the thread member function. What I get is "pure virtual method called". How can I do this?

I assume all this happens because of `&A::thread_f` in the `A` initializer list where I explicitly name a scope.

```
class A {
protected:
    std::thread _thread;

    A() : _thread(&A::thread_f, this) { }

    ~A() { 
        _thread.join();
    }

    virtual void f() = 0;

    void thread_f() {
        f();
    }
};

class B : public A {
protected:
    void f() override {
        std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: It is not safe to call member functions of `B` *before* constructing `B`, and when you're inside `A`'s constructor, `B` has not been constructed yet.

Comment: I made up this code (minimal reproducible example) from a 3rd party library. I caught a segfault there and now trying to figure out now to make it work.

Comment: The answer depends on how much freedom you have to change the code. Anyway, you have to ensure that `B` is fully constructed before you call its member functions and is destructred after all member functions call return. In your example both of these conditions are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Evg says, by starting a thread,`A` ctor call member function `f` of `B` before constructing `B`.

The solution is to start thread after B is constructed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    ~A() {
        _thread.join();
    }
    void start()
    {
        _thread = std::thread(&A::thread_f, this);
    }
protected:
    std::thread _thread;
    A()
    {
    }

    virtual void f() = 0;
    void thread_f() {
        f();
    }
};

    class B : public A {
    protected:
        void f() override
        {
            std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

void main() {
    A *pA=new B;
    pA->start();
    delete pA;
}
```

Comment: This is also problematic. `B` is destructed *before* `A` is, so the thread could be run and joined *after* `B` has already been destructed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number And why is `A::f()` called? I guess because a correct value for `vptr` in `B` has not yet been set because `B` has not yet been constructed. Note that here `f()` is called not in the constructor, but inside the thread.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If you [add a short pause](https://godbolt.org/z/rWrq7xqrq) inside `thread_f()` to make sure that `B` is constructed, this code will print `B::f()` as expected.

Comment: @Evg fwiw, this is what I used to convince myself that I was wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/6EWvfo4s4. For some reason I expected that `&A::thread_f` does not use virtual dispatch because it appears in the constructor

Comment: @Evg he/she is correct.my answer is not good .me found a better answer here go: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors

Comment: @kenash0625 There is a difference between calling a virtual function inside a constructor and inside a thread initialized in a constructor.

Comment: no virtual function calls in ctor/dtor  is it the same for ```this``` pointer?  I guess this is why @GeNtlE get the error   "pure virtual method called".

Comment: GeNtlE calls a virtual function not from a constructor but from a thread.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't work is due to c++'s [order of construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). When a class is constructed, any base classes are constructed before the derived class.

This means that when you call the virtual function `f()` in your base class, class B has not yet been constructed. This means the only available option is to try and call A's implementation of `f()`. The problem here is that A doesn't have an implementation of `f()` and thus the error occurs.

For ways to solve this, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors). I would suggest moving your call to f() into a separate initialisation stage that can be called after construction, which will mean both base and derived classes will have been fully constructed by the time of the call.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here, both related to the absence of synchronization.

The first problem is that a virtual call could be made on an object that has not yet been fully constructed. A new thread is created *before* the construction of `B`, `f()` is called inside that thread and there is no guarantee that by that time `B` is fully constructed. The behaviour is undefined.

Going into some implementation details, virtual calls are typically implemented using virtual tables. A pointer to a virtual table is set during `B`'s construction by a compiler, and if you call `f()` before that pointer is correctly set, you're likely to call `A::f()` instead of `B::f()`. Calling `A::f()` generates the "pure virtual method called" error message. Note that `f()` is called inside a thread, not inside a constructor, so that the call will be virtual and won't be resolved to `A::f()` at compile time.

The second problem is that a virtual call could be made on an object that has already been destructed. The destructor of `A`, in which you join a thread, is called *after* the destruction of `B`. Again, making a virtual call on a destructed object is undefined behaviour.

To get some insight into what's going on, you can add two mutexes:

```
std::mutex m1, m2;

struct A {
    std::thread thread;
    
    A() : thread(&A::thread_f, this) { 
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~A() { 
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
        thread.join();
    }

    virtual void f() = 0;
    
    void thread_f() {
        std::cout << "thread_f()" << std::endl;        
        m1.lock();
        f();
        m2.unlock();
    }
};

struct B : A {
    B() {
        std::cout << "B()" << std::endl;
        m1.unlock();
    }

    ~B() {
        m2.lock();    
        std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl;
    }

    void f() override {
        std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    m1.lock();
    m2.lock();
    B b;
}
```

Now you'll see the expected "`B::f()`" output. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WYKzenTes). I would hardly call this a solution, though.

The answer by **kenash0625** addresses the first problem, but it doesn't address the second one.