# Exploring the Implications of Virtual Method Calls in Constructors in C++

Tags: c++

```
class A : public B
{
    public:
    
    A()
    {
      Handle();
    }
    
    private:
    
    void ApplyHandle() override
    {
        //..
    }
}

class B
{
    public:
    
    void Handle() { ApplyHandle(); }
    
    private:
    virtual void ApplyHandle() = 0;
    
};

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that calling virtual methods in constructors is generally considered unsafe in C++. However, in this design, the **`ApplyHandle`** method is called within the **`A`** class constructor. Does this pose a risk of invoking undefined behavior, or is it safe in this context?

Does making the **`ApplyHandle`** method private and virtual have any positive impact in mitigating the concerns associated with calling virtual methods in constructors?

Would declaring **`ApplyHandle`** as **`final`** in the **`Derived`** class offer any benefits or further ensure safety in this scenario?

I am keen to understand the best practices and any potential pitfalls with this design pattern, especially in the context of complex hierarchical structures in C++.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/why-is-a-call-to-a-virtual-member-function-in-the-constructor-a-non-virtual-call, it explains exactly why what you're doing is not okay.

Comment: One question per post.

Comment: Don't use `stdio.h` in modern c++.

Comment: *I am aware that calling virtual methods in constructors is generally considered unsafe in C++.* Not really. It's perfectly safe, because it's well-defined in C++ standard. But what it does may be unexpected for programmers.

Comment: It's not *unsafe* in any way. In fact, since the `Derived` object doesn't exist yet, not dispatching to it is the safe thing to do.

Comment: BTW: `void Base : public Derived`? Please post proper code.

Comment: Your question is based on the false premise that calling virtual methods in a constructor would be unsafe or could lead to undefined behaviour, but thats not true. Maybe if you tell us what makes you think it would be unsafe or pose a risk, we could tell you where your line of reasoning is off.

Comment: Virtual function calls in constructors and destructors (C++) - https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0891/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware that calling virtual methods in constructors is generally considered unsafe in C++.

"Unwise" would be a better word choice than "unsafe". There is no danger of undefined behavior, only of unexpected behavior due to incorrect expectations. The compiler knows that [the virtual call mechanism is ineffective in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962132/9837301), but humans reading the code might expect something different. This could lead to bugs.

> However, in this design, the **`ApplyHandle`** method is called within the **`A`** class constructor. Does this pose a risk of invoking undefined behavior, or is it safe in this context?

The behavior is well-defined. The function call occurs while executing the body of the constructor of `A`, so the function that will be called is `A::ApplyHandle()`. Always. No matter what. Virtual dispatch is (as-if) ignored.

The same holds if the virtual function is invoked while initializing data members. The only time during the construction of `A` when `ApplyHandle()` would invoke a different function is during the construction of the base class. The construction of `A` begins with the construction of `B`. During the construction of `B`, `ApplyHandle()` means `B::ApplyHandle()`. After `B` is fully constructed and until `A` is fully constructed, `ApplyHandle()` means `A::ApplyHandle()`. After that point, construction might move on to a more-derived class, in which case the pattern continues until all constructors have finished.

Note that since `B::ApplyHandle()` is **pure** virtual, invoking `ApplyHandle()` in the constructor of `B` would be undefined behavior. This is because `B::ApplyHandle()` has no definition, not directly because it is virtual.

> Does making the **`ApplyHandle`** method private and virtual have any positive impact in mitigating the concerns associated with calling virtual methods in constructors?

Visibility is irrelevant.

> Would declaring **`ApplyHandle`** as **`final`** in the **`Derived`** class offer any benefits or further ensure safety in this scenario?

Using `final` would remove the incorrect expectation.

The other suggestion in the Core Guidelines is to qualify the name. That is, writing out `A::ApplyHandle()` sidesteps virtual dispatch and makes it clear that the intent is to call the function defined at this level of the class hierarchy.

> I am keen to understand the best practices and any potential pitfalls with this design pattern, especially in the context of complex hierarchical structures in C++.

C++ Core Guideline C.82: [Don't call virtual functions in constructors and destructors](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c82-dont-call-virtual-functions-in-constructors-and-destructors).

C++ Core Guideline C.50: [Use a factory function if you need "virtual behavior" during initialization](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c50-use-a-factory-function-if-you-need-virtual-behavior-during-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Formally: during the construction of a base class `Base`, the object is `Base`, and the call to a virtual function will resolve as if the most derived type were `Base`: to a function in `Base` or in a class `Base` itself derives from. If that function is abstract (as in your example), the behavior is undefined. If the function isn't abstract, it will be called, however; a function which overrides it in a more derived class will **not** be called.

This is to avoid calling a function on a class whose constructor has not yet been entered. If you need to call a function in the derived class from the base class, the simplest and safest solution is to factor out the functionality in question into a delegate, which is passed into the base class constructor. The derived class then creates the delegate as part of the argument to the base class, and the delegate is fully constructed before the base class constructor is called.